# biblio author initials two character

Tags: 7, entities

I have `Drupal 7` with [biblio 7.x-1.0-rc7](https://www.drupal.org/project/biblio/releases/7.x-1.0-rc7) module.

How can I set up the biblio module that the initial of an author to be more then one character. I know it is a strange request, but e.g. in Hungarian the character combination zs, sz, ty, gy, ... are one letter (sound).
So a name like **Jeno Szabo** has initial **J. Sz.** 
This thing happens in other languages too, like Romanian: Ge, Ce, Ghe, Che, ... 
**Pop Gheorghe** initials are **P. Ghe.**

How can I set so in case of some authors I would define the initial in the biblio module?

I found the filed in author setup: `Prefix _ First Name _  Initials _ Last Name _ Suffix _`
I don't understand how the Initials filed works (maybe this is not the solution). for example: author **Jeno Szabo** I want to be displayed as **Jeno Sz**.

So the author setup filed should be like:

`Prefix _ First Name Szabo  Initials Sz J Last Name Jeno Suffix _`
result: `Jeno SSz J`

OR

`Prefix _ First Name Szabo  Initials z Last Name Jeno Suffix _`
result: `Jeno Sz` in the publication, but if I search between the authors list still appears as `Jeno S`. 
So, this is deinitly not the correct solution to generate initials from two character.

My bug report can be found here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2460733

Comment: This seems a bug report more than a question. You should post this bug inthe module's issue queue https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/biblio?categories=1

Comment: Thx for pointing me in to the right direction.